# Detect which input / select was changed and get its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, input

As you can see, my inputs and selects are executing a function. In that function I need to detect which input or select was modified and get its value.

How can I do this? Can't find a good answer to fit my needs.

```
<input type="text" name="1" id="1" onchange="some_function"/>
<input type="text" name="2" id="2" onchange="some_function"/>
<select name="3" id="3" onchange="some_function">
    <option></option>
</select>
<select name="4" id="4" onchange="some_function">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: have you looked into `this` in javascript?

Comment: Take a look into MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver, it helps you do exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @versvs that won't help in this case as changing the value of an input doesn't affect the DOM at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't use event attributes. Hook up your events using unobtrusive event handlers.

Secondly, to solve your actual issue, you can use the `this` keyword within the event handler to reference the element that raised the event. From there you can retrieve the required properties of the element. As you're using jQuery you can do it like this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input').on('input', some_function);
  $('select').on('change', some_function);
});

function some_function() {
  console.log(`${this.name} = ${this.value}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="1" id="1" />
<input type="text" name="2" id="2" />
<select name="3" id="3">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
<select name="4" id="4">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in javascript by passing the element using `this` keyword.And for input fields `onchange` will not work. You have to use `oninput`

```js
function some_function(obj){
console.log(obj.id +"changed with value-" +obj.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="1" id="1" oninput="some_function(this)"/>
<input type="text" name="2" id="2" oninput="some_function(this)"/>
<select name="3" id="3" onchange="some_function(this)">
   <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<select name="4" id="4" onchange="some_function(this)">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way:

```js
function some_function(thatVal){
  var val = '';
  if($(thatVal)[0].nodeName=='SELECT'){
    var id = $(thatVal).attr('id');
    val = $('#'+id+' option:selected').text();
  }
  else{
    val = $(thatVal).val();
  }
  console.log(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="1" id="1" onchange="some_function(this)"/><br>
<input type="text" name="2" id="2" onchange="some_function(this)"/><br>
<select name="3" id="3" onchange="some_function(this)">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="4" id="4" onchange="some_function(this)">
    <option>X</option>
    <option>Y</option>
</select>
```